# How can I get action events to work with template strings

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

**Problem**

Rendered HTML template literal action events won't work

Stack MEVN with handlebars

***code***

**renderData.js**

```
const template = function (data)  {
  return `<div class="vvn_siteContent sc_flex">
  <span class="sc_flex">
    <img src="https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/single/keyboard_backlight_light_159518_1280x720.jpg" alt="" class="sc_img">
    <div class="sc_flex sc_column">
      <label class="sc_label">${data.category} :: ${data.titles.main}</label>
      <div class="sc_desc" style="word-wrap: break-word">
 ${data.desc.main}

      </div>
      <div class="vvn_editTypes">
        <button class="sc_button sc_resetBTN">Delete</button>
       <button class="sc_button sc_scheduleBTN" >Hide</button>
        <button class="sc_button sc_sendBTN" dataset-data="${data._id}" onclick="myData()" >Edit!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>`
}

export const renderData = function (key) {
  const keyToLowerCase = key.toLowerCase();
  const getKeyData = handleJSON(keyToLowerCase);
  getContainer.innerHTML = " ";
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  for (let i = 0; i < getKeyData[0][0].pageContent.length; i++) {
    const { ...data } = getKeyData[0][0].pageContent[i];

    const html = template(data);
    const parsedDoc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
    getContainer.append(...parsedDoc.body.children);
  }
}
```

**oneCRUD.js** //this is the file that is loaded via

`<script type="module" src="../js/OneCRUD.js" type="text/javascript" data="{{data2}}"></script>`

this script tag is at the bottom of the `index.html`

```
const allBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.vvn_editTypes').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target)
    console.log(e)
    if(e.target.textContent === 'Delete') console.log('Deleting')
    if(e.target.textContent === 'Hide') console.log('Hiding')
    if(e.target.textContent === 'Edit!') console.log('Editing')
}))

function myData () {
    console.log('this wont get called even if i gave the button onclick="myData()")
}
```

If I try to call a function in `onclick` I will get error `function name undefined`

My problem is pretty straight forward. I am trying to attach events to the buttons in `renderData.js` from file `oneCRUD.js` and its not working.

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

*code*

```
const allBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.vvn_siteContent').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target)
    console.log(e)
    if(e.target.textContent === 'Delete') console.log('Deleting')
    if(e.target.textContent === 'Hide') console.log('Hiding')
    if(e.target.textContent === 'Edit!') console.log('Editing')
}))
```

notice how the element I'm selecting is inside the template literal [image: this is the targeted element from allBtns]

I need to select the parent of that element. [image]

so now my code looks like this:

```
const allBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.vvn_siteContentList').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target)
    console.log(e)
    if(e.target.textContent === 'Delete') console.log('Deleting')
    if(e.target.textContent === 'Hide') console.log('Hiding')
    if(e.target.textContent === 'Edit!') console.log('Editing')
}))
```

now the `allBtns` function works.

**why does this work?**

thats a good question